# How to use ArrayFlatten

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to use the ArrayFlatten command to create an 8 by 8 matrix of zeros from 4 dimensional column vectors as shown below.

```
s = ConstantArray[0, 4];
{{s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}, {s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}} // MatrixForm
ArrayFlatten[{{s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}, {s, s, s, s, s, s, s, 
    s}}] // MatrixForm
```

However, the ArrayFlatten does not do anything here. Please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For new learners visiting the page: `ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}] // MatrixForm` should generate the desired matrix. This question is about the use of `ArrayFlatten` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `s` to be a matrix before using `ArrayFlatten`

Help says

> creates a single flattened matrix from a matrix of matrices
> Subscript[m, ij]

But your `s` was not a matrix.

```
s = ConstantArray[0, 4]
InputForm[s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make it a matrix of 4 columns you need to do

```
s = Transpose[{s}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now you can use it with `ArrayFlatten`

```
s = ConstantArray[0, 4]
s = Transpose[{s}]
(mat = ArrayFlatten[{{s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}, {s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

@Nasser gave the canonical answer and this is more of a general comment, hopefully useful.

Instead of using [ArrayFlatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) you can consider [ArrayReshape](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html)

That is

```
x = ConstantArray[0, 4];
x = Thread@{x};
matx = ArrayReshape[Table[x, {i, 1, 8}], {8, 8}];
```

You can check that

```
MatrixForm@matx
```

> [image: matx]

and also

```
matx === mat
```

> `True`

with `mat` being the answer by @Nasser

Answer (score 5):

```
s = ConstantArray[0, 4];
(t = {s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}) // MatrixForm
```

This is a 8x4 matrix, since each `s` is a row of four elements. Put two of these side by side in a single row, two column arrangement, to get a 8x8 matrix:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{t, t}}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

Or start with a block that is a 4x4 matrix:

```
t = {s, s, s, s}; MatrixForm@t
```

and make two columns and two rows from these sub-elements.

```
(ArrayFlatten[{{t, t}, {t, t}}]) // MatrixForm
```

to get the same 8x8 matrix as above.